# Calling function from parent to child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to get my head around this idea - I believe it may be going against design rules for React - but still can't figure out how to do it better.

I've got an application with quite a few modal forms that may pop up - and I'm trying to ensure they're all consistent in the UI aspect. As a result, I made a "GenericModal" component, which can take title / formComponent or body/buttons. This works well and got it to populate the component.

The problem is that I can't figure out how I get my buttons to interact with the formComponent. I've tried passing refs through, but for some reason, I couldn't get that to work at 2 am, gave up, and went to bed.

Can anyone suggest anything that I'm missing? I have considered that I'm trying to get the form component to do too much (i.e, I should be passing a formik instance *to* the form, so that I can then interact with it from the component hosting the ).

```
function GenericModal(props) {
  return (
    props.show && (
      <Modal
        show={props.show}
        onHide={props.handleClose}
        backdrop="static"
        keyboard={false}
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton={props.closeButton && props.closeButton}>
          <Modal.Title>{props.title ? props.title : "Modal"}</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
          {props.formComponent ? props.formComponent : props.body && props.body}
        </Modal.Body>

        {props.buttons && (
          <Modal.Footer>
            {props.buttons &&
              props.buttons.map((button) => (
                <Button
                  variant={button.style}
                  key={button.key}
                  onClick={() => handleButtonClick(button.key)}
                >
                  {button.text}
                </Button>
              ))}
          </Modal.Footer>
        )}
      </Modal>
    )
  );
}

export default GenericModal;
```

The buttons will call handleButtonClick, which for "submit" or "reset" I was originally thinking to fire functions on formComponent.

This component is then used as follows:

```
      {showNewModal && (
        <GenericModal
          show={showNewModal}
          handleClose={closeNewModal}
          title="New Asset"
          formComponent={<AssetForm asset={new Asset()} />}
          closeButton={true}
          buttons={
            { text: "Create", style: "primary", key: "submit" }
          }
        />
      )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood the problem, but it sounds like you want to make sure you have control over what happens when the button is clicked in the `GenericModal`?

Can you just pass the `onClick` handler as a prop instead of the `key`?

So inside your `GenericModal` you'd then use the button like this:

```
<Button onClick={props.button.onClick} />
```

This way your modal button can call a callback in the parent component and you can handle it in any way you'd like.

Comment: Hi,

Actually I mean the opposite, the nesting is as follows:

GenericDialog (which has the buttons), and an AssetForm as a child of GenericDialog.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by passing an object to the asset form from GenericModal, and having it populate the submit/reset functions into that object, so I could call that from the parent component on button press (so that Formik can validate the data, then pass back to the modal).

Bit of a hacky way of doing it, probably the wrong way, but it works!